# Problems with materialize.js 1.0.0 and jQuery 3.5.1 in a Vue CLI 4 project

Tags: jquery, vue.js, command-line-interface, materialize

My first time here. I'm new to Vue.js and I'm also trying Vue CLI for the first time.
I want to try Materialize CSS in a Vue CLI 4 project, but I'm having trouble with the jQuery part.

Just trying a sidenav for mobiles to see everything is working with the framework. But when I use ***sidenav()***, an error appears in the console indicating `"$(...).sidenav is not a function"`.
I found the same errors here in Stack Overflow, but solutions didn't work for me.
I don't want to use `<link>` tag in index.html. I want to use main.js and .vue files.
jQuery works fine and is being recognized, I checked it using `console.log($(".sidenav").html());` haha.

As it's my first time working with these files in a Vue CLI project, I thought I'm not importing them correctly, so I created another Vue CLI project using Bootstrap (not Bootstrap-Vue).
And everything works fine in that Bootstrap project using jQuery. So, I think the problem is **materialize.js**.

By the way, using pure JavaScript (from Materialize Docs) works, but using jQuery doesn't.

Notes:

```
 - Instead of using "$(function() { /* jQuery code here */ });", I use the jQuery code in the "mounted()" hook. The same for the Bootstrap project.
 - In a single HTML file (not a Vue CLI project) it works fine with jQuery (I'm using the same code).
 - Materialize CSS v1.0.0-rc.2 (according to package.json | npm install materialize-css@next --save). Also tried "npm install materialize-css@1.0.0 --save" as it's the version I used in single HTML file, but it didn't work either.
 - jQuery v3.5.1 (npm install jquery --save). Tried v2.2.4 but the same problem.
 - Using default option at vue create (babel, eslint).
 - @vue/cli 4.4.1
 - node 12.18.0
 - npm 6.14.4
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

**src/main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import './assets/css/material-icons.css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import './assets/css/estilos.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Materialize from 'materialize-css'

export const jquery = $;
export const materialize = Materialize;
// Vue.use(Materialize) // Tal vez para el JavaScript de Materialize

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  // Materialize, // Tal vez para el JavaScript de Materialize
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**src/App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <headerMenu></headerMenu>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import headerMenu from './components/headerMenu.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    headerMenu
  }
}
</script>
```

**src/components/headerMenu.vue** (the commented code is the pure JavaScript that works fine)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Site Title</a>
        <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="enlaces-moviles">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <ul class="sidenav" id="enlaces-moviles">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { jquery } from '../main';
// import { materialize } from '../main';

export default {
  mounted() {
    const $ = jquery;
    window.$ = $; // Creo que esta línea debería omitirse, de todos modos funciona sin ella.
    window.jQuery = jquery; // Tal vez una opción más.
    $(".sidenav").sidenav();

    /* const M = materialize;
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    M.Sidenav.init(elems); */
  }
}
</script>
```

**The error:**
[error_in_console.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klf1o.png)

Comment: Why not use vanilla JS? jQuery is no longer a dependency of Materialize. The error you are seeing usually occurs when jQuery is not loaded properly, and it's not afault of Materialize - otherwise the vanilla JS wouldn't work.

Comment: I just wanted to try with jQuery, but I think I'll use vanilla JavaScript... it just seemed strange to me that Bootstrap.js did work with jQuery, but Materialize.js didn't. Thanks, @SeanDoherty.

Comment: Materialize does work with jQuery - it just isn’t dependent on it. I use Materialize and jQuery together all the time in Wordpress. You just have to make sure jQuery is loaded first and that you are loading all your scripts correctly when using a js framework.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not a dependency, I found it in [https://medium.com/@materializecss/materialize-to-1-0-and-beyond-e0233b8ac15](https://medium.com/@materializecss/materialize-to-1-0-and-beyond-e0233b8ac15).
Again, it's strange to me because everything in a single HTML file works fine, but in Vue CLI 4 doesn't. And I can't figure out how to load jQuery correctly for Materialize, because for Bootstrap in Vue CLI I don't have problems haha.. But I'll keep trying; by the moment I'm getting acquainted with Vue CLI.